# How to filter an array with fetched data in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, filter

I'm trying to filter an array with fetched list of users. Users are stored in component state. I want to filter it by text from input.

Problem: When I enter letters the list is filtering, but when I delete letters result remains unchanged.

Thanks for help!!!

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: true,
        users: [],
        error: null
    }

    fetchUsers() {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>
            this.setState({
              users: data,
              isLoading: false,
            })
        )
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchUsers();
    }

    onChangeHandler(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        let newArray = this.state.users.filter((d)=>{
            let searchValue = d.name.toLowerCase();
            return searchValue.indexOf(e.target.value) !== -1;
        });
        console.log(newArray)
        this.setState({
            users:newArray
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {isLoading, users, error} = this.state;
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Users List</h1>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} placeholder="Search by user name..." onChange={this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)}/>
                    {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
                    <ol>
                    {!isLoading ? (
                        users.map(user => {
                            const {username, name, id} = user;
                            return (
                                <li key={id}>
                                    <p>{name} <span>@{username}</span></p>
                                </li>
                            );
                        })
                    ) : (
                        <h3>Loading...</h3>
                    )}
                    </ol>
                </div>
            );
      }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: well, you are removing when filtering, maybe you should just filter on the render instead, or use the `users` state only to filter down `filteredUsers` and show filteredUsers if defined, otherwise users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of storing the users list from API to a variable after using setState to update users

```
apiUsers = [];

    fetchUsers() {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>{
        this.apiUsers = data;
            this.setState({
              users: data,
              isLoading: false,
            })
            }
        )
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }
```

Instead of filtering `this.state.users` use the newly created variable - `apiUsers` in `onChangeHandler`

```
onChangeHandler(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        let newArray = this.apiUsers.filter((d)=>{
          console.log(d)
            let searchValue = d.name.toLowerCase();
            return searchValue.indexOf(e.target.value) !== -1;
        });
        console.log(newArray)
        this.setState({
            users:newArray
        })
    }
```

working code for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sncf1e?file=index.js

**Issue:** :  `state.users` array is getting updated without the copy of actual users list from api

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you do not keep a track of the original values you get from the API. Once you start filtering it, you lose the full list.

I created a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sunset-jig33 to fix your issue.

What I did is to add a `initialUsers` value in the `state` and use it to store the value coming from the API:

```
state = {
    isLoading: true,
    initialUsers: [],
    users: [],
    inputValue: "",
    error: null
  };

 fetchUsers() {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          initialUsers: data,
          isLoading: false
        })
      )
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

and in the `render` method, I switch between displaying the filtered list of the original list by checking if a text is entered in the `input` element

```
(!!inputValue ? users : initialUsers).map(
              user => {
                const { username, name, id } = user;
                return (
                  <li key={id}>
                    <p>
                      {name} <span>@{username}</span>
                    </p>
                  </li>
                );
              }
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you logically look at your current solution then you have the following situation

- users is an empty array, with isLoading true
- users are fetched and pushed in the array, lets assume `['John', 'Joe', 'Alfred']`
- you filter your users for the letter `J` and update the user state to  `['John', 'Joe']`
- You remove the filter for letter `J` and update the user state to `['John', 'Joe']` cause the component completely forgot about `Alfred`, you deleted hem in step 3

So, you have several options, just filter the render before the mapping, depending on how many users, that shouldn't be that bad or create more than 1 property on the state, say `filteredUsers` which contains the list of `users` that match your filter, and work with that state instead.

The cool thing about your current filter, is that it will always go faster, as your resultset kind of trims down, so that's a good thing, but I doubt you'll be dealing with so many users that you need this.